# Instantiate and present viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I switch between views in my app with the following code:

```
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    settingsVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingsVC") as! SettingsVC
    self.present(settingsVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This works fine, for instance from a main menu, after a press of a button. But I did this a few times after each other going back and forward from the menu to the settings view and I noticed that the view loads as many times as I went back and forward. So it probably creates the view controller again and again. How can I make sure it does in only once. So is there a way to check whether the view controller does exist. As a sidenote: I do not work with a navigation controller, just a few plain viewcontrollers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are presenting view that is reason, you should push with navigationController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options. I, like Ayaz, recommend doing this in a navigation controller but if for some reason you don't want to, I would recommend dismissing the SettingsVC when you are done with it. You can do this by calling `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` after hitting the "close" or "back" button.

Answer (score 1):

> So is there a way to check whether the view controller does exist.

It *doesn't* exist. You yourself create it here, so you *know* it is created. But it is also destroyed when the opposite happens, i.e. when the view controller you present with `present` is dismissed. That is expected and correct. If you want state to be preserved between instantiations and restored on the next instantiation, it is up to you to preserve and restore it.